# sequelize is slow with and without caching

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following sequelize code:

```
async function findAllRatePlans() {
    return await db.rate_plans.cache('all').findAll({
        include: [
            { model: db.pricings },
            { model: db.services },
            { model: db.usps_evs_accounts }
        ]
    });
}
```

This produces the following query (without cache):

```
SELECT 
"rate_plans"."id", 
"rate_plans"."tag", 
"rate_plans"."service_id" AS "serviceId", 
...
"pricing"."id" AS "pricing.id", 
"pricing"."name" AS "pricing.name", 
"pricing"."api_name" AS "pricing.apiName", 
...
"usps_evs_account"."id" AS "usps_evs_account.id", 
"usps_evs_account"."default" AS "usps_evs_account.default", 
... 
FROM "rate_plans" AS "rate_plans" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "pricings" AS "pricing" ON "rate_plans"."pricing_id" = "pricing"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "services" AS "service" ON "rate_plans"."service_id" = "service"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "usps_evs_accounts" AS "usps_evs_account" ON "rate_plans"."nsa_usps_evs_account_id" = "usps_evs_account"."id"
```

There are approximately 50 columns that are part of the select statement.

A rate_plan is defined as belongsTo pricings, belongsTo services and belongsTo usps_evs_accounts.

This is my first major Node and sequelize project and I'm trying to find out why the code is running so slow. I added the newrelic module to instrument things and it looks like the sequelize calls are very slow. Initially I was hitting the db directly but then I installed **sequelize-transparent-cache**; unfortunately that had little impact on the overall performance. NewRelic shows that the  `findAllRatePlans()` function (when using the cache) takes 62.32ms. Perhaps my expectations of Node are wrong, but I thought this should be much faster. I have the same code in Ruby and it's running 10X faster. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: what did you do in rails? used ActiveRecord ? sequelize is an ORM layer on top of DAO, it parses and deduplicating results, you can try to run your queries without the magic with "raw:true" flag, or  you can try the sequelize.query() to run a raw query , or use "seperate:true" if you have 1:m relations in your nested includes.

Comment: Yes, ActiveRecord, but I do have some caching solution enabled. Slowly I'm beginning to think it might not be sequelize. I wrote my own cache and different environments yield different performance numbers. I'll do more digging before I respond with my research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this SQL query wasn't specific enough and it ended up returning about 1000 rows, so about 50,000 fields. All together, this was approximately 2MB of data being serialized into Javascript objects. My problem is also that the code is overall very OO with lots of domain objects. I think sequelize-transparent-cache caches raw data and not Javascript objects. I ended up writing my own Redis cache which serialized Javascript objects and I got a performance improvement, but I couldn't store the object type, so I still had to do a new object 1000 times. ActiveRecord and the cache mechanism was better at keeping track of the object types during serialization and deserialization. In the end, adding more where clauses to my original SQL query resulted in less records and a big performance increase.